# Objective C - NSDictionary giving error for CTParagraphStyleRef?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

```
CTParagraphStyleRef paraStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignSettings, 1);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paraStyle forKey:kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```

I get a warning on the second line of code "Passing argument 2 from incompatible pointer type "
How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

`paraStyle` is no object, so you cant store it as one. try [`setValue:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000141-BAJJCBIE) on a NSMuteableDictionary and `valueForKey:` to retrieve it.

Or wrap your value in a [NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG) object.

Comment: I am still getting a warning. Everything works but I don't like to have warnings in my code

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the warning because `kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName` is not an object and can't be used as a key in an `NSMutableDictionary`. Keys in an `NSMutableDictionary` must be Objective-C objects that conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. The `CTParagraphStyleRef` can't be stored in the dictionary either, because it is likewise not an Obj-C object.

You may want to try using a [`CFMutableDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/), whose keys and values can be any C type.